# Couldnt load file Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.12.0 when cshtml file opened in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor, visual-studio-2015

I have installed visual studio 2015 and when i started my project of VS 2013 into 2015. AFter opening .cshtml file i get error that error is logged in activity.xml file.

I have also tried to create new project and same problem is occuring in there.
The ViewBag and Model doenst appear to known to IDE error as the viewbag doesnt exist in current context.

I opened the path and get the following error

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.12.0, Version=12.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. File name:
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.12.0, Version=12.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' at
>   MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.Html.HtmlViewCreationListener.textView_MouseHover(Object
>   sender, MouseHoverEventArgs e) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.Implementation.WpfTextView.RaiseHoverEvents()
>   WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF. To enable assembly bind
>   failure logging, set the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. Note: There
>   is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure
>   logging. To turn this feature off, remove the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

How to solve this error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed these steps in order to completely re-install Visual Studio 2015 which solved the problem. Repair didnt work

run the command

```
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe /resetuserdata
```

Downloaded the web installer setup file and run the following command in the downloaded directory

```
    vs_community.exe /uninstall /force
```

After Uninstalling i made sure no file software related to VS is installed and restarted PC
    Installed new Visual Studio using Web Installer.

Run the command again.

```
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe /resetuserdata



  Updates were available inside Visual Studio , installed them - Restarted Visual Studio

    Now open any asp.net mvc solution it takes time though in start but after that it works.
```

Source : [MVC Not Working In Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32937222/visual-studio-2015-new-mvc-project-the-mvc-does-not-exist-in-microsoft-aspnet)